# i am getting an error in NSURL

Tags: swift, swift3

**here is my code...**

```
@IBAction func recordAction(_ sender: Any) {

 if  self.audioRecorder.isRecording {

   self.audioRecorder.stop()

  self.rcdBtn.setTitle("Record", for: UIControlState.normal)

    }else {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do{

    try session.setActive(true)

    }catch{
            print("error to recording")
        }
        audioRecorder.record()
        rcdBtn.setTitle("Finish Recording", for: UIControlState.normal)

    }
}





 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    let baseString: String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    let pathComponents = [baseString,"MyAudio.mp3"]

   self.audioUrl = NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: pathComponents)! as NSURL

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()


    do{
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    }catch{
            print("Error")
    }


    var recordSettings: [String :Any] = Dictionary()
    recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
    recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
    recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

    do{
      self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: self.audioUrl as! URL, settings: recordSettings)
    }catch{
        print("Error at setting ")
    }
    //Super init is below
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

**i am doing a simple Audio Recording project, using AVFoundation frameworks...**

**And this error i am getting.......**

**-[NSURL init] called; this results in an NSURL instance with an empty URL string. Please use one of the documented NSURL initialization methods instead (initWithString:, initFileURLWithPath:**

Comment: `NSURL.fileURL(withPathComponents: pathComponents)! as NSURL` Why are you doing this?! This is not how it works. Create an instance using `NSURL(` and the initializer you need. Do not call a static one and do not cast to its own type...